# Detect and remove outliers from unknown distribution

Tags: distributions, outliers

I have completed a range of steady-state CFD simulations on building roofs. A contour map of the resulting variable is displayed in the Figure below with the corresponding values on the left side. Each cell on the map contains a value of the variable. I also plotted the variable in a box plot to analyze it and it was not normally distributed.

I want to find one representative value of this variable for the whole roof, but I also want to detect any outliers and remove them as they are a method error in this kind of simulation. Winsorization does not seem as too good of an idea in this case.

I have tried to use modified Z values (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11882393/matplotlib-disregard-outliers-when-plotting)) and removed data that is labeled as outliers. Otherwise, I have thought about using box plots to label and remove the outliers. Then the median will be calculated by the remaining dataset. Do any of these methods work for unknown distributions? Any alternatives?

[image: Figure]

Comment: Exactly what about the roof are you trying to represent?  It plausibly could be the highest value, the lowest value, the integral, some kind of mean, etc.  Why do you even care about the distribution, given that the spatial variation is likely of far more interest in such applications?

Comment: I want to find the median, but I want to remove the outliers first

Comment: Removing the outliers is unlikely to change the median by much, if at all.  That's one of the reasons for using the median.

Comment: I agree. But let's say you want to remove the outliers. Can the modified Z value method be used for an unknown distribution to label the outliers, then remove the labeled outliers from the dataset?

Comment: "Outlier" has no general definition.  You have to begin by characterizing them somehow and go on from there.  In your case the definition plausibly would be related to their values, their values relative to their neighbors, and their locations -- but you haven't been sufficiently specific about that.

Comment: Boris Iglewicz and David Hoaglin (1993), "Volume 16: How to Detect and
        Handle Outliers" recommends a threshold value of 3.5. What if I use that value instead of characterizing a threshold value based on the physical variable?

Comment: That is an omnibus procedure designed for quick, initial screening of univariate data.  You seem to be beyond that now.  But if you want to learn more about it, search our site for threads that discuss both *boxplots* and *outliers.*